# PHPUnit stderr ignored

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I want to run some functional/integration tests (not unit tests) with PhpUnit. It works well, except in some cases gives the following error:

**Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at phar://C:/easyphp/binaries/php/php_runningversion/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Util/Printer.php:137)**

This happens when trying to modify header information, e.g. `seassion_start`, `set_cookie`, `redirect`, etc. There is a fix for this, the `--stderr` run time option or the `stderr="true"`xml configuration, which redirects output to stderr thus not starting the output. This worked great on Netbeans.

**Yet, none of these seem to work with PhpStorm. Any idea why?**

Here's the command line (created by PhpStorm):

```
C:\easyphp\binaries\php\php_runningversion\php.exe   
    C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php 
    --stderr
    --bootstrap C:\easyphp\data\localweb\tests\bootstrap.php
    --configuration C:\easyphp\data\localweb\tests\configuration.xml
    C:\easyphp\data\localweb\tests
```

The config file:

```
<phpunit colors="false" stderr="true" />
```

Comment: You can  Suppress the output to console, adding this line on the test method   `$this->setOutputCallback(function() {});` hope this help

Comment: Run/Debug Configuration for PHPUnit supports passing command line arguments where [you can pass](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-8994#comment=27-278613) `--stderr`. As I understand you already doing this. If this does not work .. then I may suggest to try adding `-d output_buffering=On` to the "Interpreter Options" [as suggested here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-8994#comment=27-346846), which has some disadvantages.

Comment: @LazyOne This doesn't seem to work either. Nothing chaqnged (except the `php.exe -d output_buffering=On` call).

Comment: Well ... what can I say: the ticket on Issue Tracker says that it *should* work. Maybe something is broken in last versions somehow... Can you create some simple project that would reproduce the problem and share it (whole self-contained project) so that I can just open it and try here on my PC? AT least I could confirm then that this is a reproducible case.